# Webpack 4 - Sourcemaps

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

This article [webpack 4: mode and optimization](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a) seems to suggest that when `mode` is set to `development` the `devtool` is set to `eval`.

I was expecting this to trigger sourcemap generation but running the [webpack-4-quickstart](https://github.com/valentinogagliardi/webpack-4-quickstart) in either `development` or `production` mode results in no sourcemaps being generated.

How can I generate sourcemaps with webpack 4?

Comment: Seems misleading, as the bug is fixed, you still have to set devtool configuration option.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think what you are expecting is **extracted file** including source maps like 'bundle.js.map', but `eval` type doesn't generate separate file:

> eval - Each module is executed with eval() and //@ sourceURL. This is
>   pretty fast. The main disadvantage is that it doesn't display line
>   numbers correctly since it gets mapped to transpiled code instead of
>   the original code (No Source Maps from Loaders).

But you can always do it by manually configuring `devtool` property like:

```
devtool: 'source-map'
```

which will extract source-maps to a file. [Here are described types of sourcemaps](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool) along with their costs and benefits.

**EDIT:**

Actually there [is a issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6614#issuecomment-369376775) on github with a PR related to this. Right now UglifyJS plugin has set `sourceMap: false` even in production mode and it doesn't let extracting source-maps to separate file even with `devtool` set.

Comment: It seems the above issue under EDIT: has been Closed and it no longer appears to be an issue with webpack@4.29.0.

Comment: Where are the source map generated ?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest setup is to add the `devtool: 'source-maps'` as before.

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  ...
};
```

But this generates sourcemaps both for `development` or `production` mode.